# Calling countdown function inside catch/error of $http.post doesn't execute in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I have this simple code which calls countdown timer inside catch function of $http.post .

```
this.$http.post('/api/task/post', updatedTask ,function(data){
              alert('success!')
}).catch(function(data){
              alert('Error!');
              vm.StartTimer(captionClass);
});
```

But, when an error occurs vm.StartTimer(captionClass) doesn't execute, then  tried to call that same function inside click event, and it does work.

```
TestCounter: function(){
            vm.StartTimer('.tm-task-caption-title-1');
},
```

Here is the countdown timer function

```
StartTimer: function(display) {
            var counter = 5;
            var interval =setInterval(function() {
                $(display).html(counter);
                counter--;
                if(counter == 0){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }

            }, 1000);
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

What have worked for me is the syntax used in [vue-resource docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md), in your case, it should be:

```
this.$http.post('/api/task/post', updatedTask ,function(data){
          alert('success!')
}, function(data){
          alert('Error!');
          vm.StartTimer(captionClass);
});
```

As you can see, there is no catch part. Vue resource use a custom implementation of promises, so I'm not pretty sure if there is support for that catch function in Http method. Anyway, I have used promises with vue resource, but using the [resource method](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/resource.md)